# Does a convert say kaddish for his parents when they pass?

Tags: halacha-theory, conversion-to-judaism, mourning-aveilus, kaddish

Does a convert say kaddish for his parents when they pass? If yes is this limited to a Jewish parent (father) or does this include a non Jewish parent? If it does include a non-Jewish parent would it be limited to a Noahide or monotheistic parent?

Comment: https://aish.com/convert-mourning-kaddish-for-non-jewish-parent/

Comment: @Chatzkel So you should write an actual answer with your link explaining that essentially the answer is no, and then maybe expound on the broader concept as it pertains to convert.

Comment: This is not a repeat. This question asks about more details

Comment: @Dude the question asks about more details but the answers to the other question also apply to this question

Comment: @Dude the question says that the father is not doing well, but still alive. There is hope!

Comment: About a father who is Jewish: even if you aren't considered related to him according to halacha, he is a Jew and deserves to have Kaddish said for him. As I understand, any Jewish male, regardless if they are related, can say Kaddish for him, so for sure his biological son (even if not halachically related) can.